# This device isn't eligible for the requested build

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, itunes, xcode-organizer

I have an iPad 1st gen with with iOS 4.3.5 is the current software version. I am trying to upgrade to "iOS 5 beta 6", but I am getting this error message

**This device isn't eligible for the requested build**

note: 
- my iPad device is a registered development device.
- I tried removing the gs.apple.com entry in localhost file, reboot itune/my mac etc but it didn't work.
- I have iTunes 10.5 beta 6 installed on my MacBook.
- I am running Lion - OS is up to date.

Comment: I got a similar error when trying to update an older 3G to 4.x+.  It may be incompatible. They may add support at the end for the final release, but who knows with Apple.

Comment: thanks David. I guess the questions is now, any idea how to locate iOS 5 [beta 1 to 5] files on the developer website?

Comment: Same exact problem here.

Answer (score 0):

> I guess the questions is now, any idea how to locate iOS 5 [beta 1 to 5] files on the developer website?

Are you asking where the betas are?  If you log into the iOS Dev Center, there is a tab up top called "iOS SDK Beta" and it looks like there is a beta for iPad 1 (but not iPhone 3G).

Comment: Yes, I can see the beta tab, but that webpage offers the latest beta (specifically beta 5) well now it's beta 6.
I am looking for beta1, beta2 etc... beta5. It looks like you can't upgrade from  iOS 4.3.5 to beta5. It has to happen incrementally. See @David comment

Comment: I had to wait for the GM seed to test my Apps on iOS5.